# Not Sure How To Use ADO .Properties("Partial Bulk Ops")

Tags: ms-access, vba, primary-key

As the title says.. I see the [documentation on ADODB `.Properties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140022%28v=office.10%29.aspx), but I'm not really sure how to use it. I need to temporarily enable the Execute to ignore key violations (aka only import one, as the native access queries do with the warning (warning not necessary)).

I've tried

```
Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
cnn.Properties("Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops") = 1
cnn.BeginTrans
' do my sql which works
cnn.CommitTrans
```

However on `cnn.Properties(...` it produces the following error:

`Read-only property value was not set`

I'm a little out of my league on this one.. havn't delved into this stuff before.

If anyone knows of another way to ignore these key violations in VBA without using `DoCmd`, that would work just as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

With cnn
   .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"

   .Properties("Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops") = 1
   .Open "z:\docs\test.accdb"
End With
```

I imagine `CurrentProject.Connection` does not work because it is open `cnn.state=adStateOpen`

Comment: I think you're right; however using this method, `The database has been placed in a state by user 'XXX' on machine 'XXXXXX' that prevents it from being opened or locked`. Seems like it can't open two connections from the same database?

Comment: The really annoying thing about ADODB in the current access application is that you must save every time just before you run. Usually ctrl+s in the code window will do, but occasionally you just have to exit and open, but that might just be me.

Comment: Huh.. I wonder if maybe I'm taking the wrong approach to this; maybe I should try DoCmd instead? Or another way of turning off the Partial limits? However you've been spot on so far with your answers.

Comment: I would generally start from DoCmd.Transfer ... but I don't know what you want to do. Mostly I import into a scratch table, check, and append, but I can see that may not suit.

Comment: It would take some manoeuvring but that may be the better way to go. This is actually a side-problem from my question yesterday about importing only MAX() with key violations etc from 3 offline db's. Importing then dealing with the data locally might be the better option.